# data type issue with image URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I can't seem to work it out...

```
group[PF_GROUP_FEATURED] is just a database reference to a URL. I am trying to get these images to show up in my tableView cells.
```

My error is "incompatible pointer types sending UIImage to parameter type NSString.."

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:group[PF_GROUP_LOGO]]]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your group[PF_GROUP_FEATURED]? Looks like that is an image rather than a string?

Comment: the link is a string stored in my database. It is a type string named Logo (i had featured as a typo, i fixed it but it didnt fix my issue)

Comment: `cell.imageView.image = image;` not `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];`

Comment: ^wow im a dummy... that did it! post it as an answer

Comment: You are passing Image rather than ImageName .... Just Use
cell.imageView.image=image;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cell.imageView.image = image;`

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

Answer (score 4):

cell.imageView.image = image ;